# Code Editor with Double Click Selection

Tags: text-editors, highlighting

Are there any free text editors that highlight text based on <s>evaluation order</s> tokenization order?  The target language currently are C, Javascript, and HTML.  But a questioned generalized to other languages like C#, C++ would likely be most useful.

For example if you double click on `console` in the following example

```
   if(x){
     console.log("test");
   }
```

`console.log("test")` like so should be highlighted.

[image]

Then if you continue to double click the next level should be highlighted like so.

[image]

Lot's of editors support syntax highlighting but I can't find editors that seem to support double clicking selection(that is what I am currently calling it).   I can think of one editor that supports such functionality although it certainly isn't free.

**EDIT:**: Ideally the editor still supports auto indenting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example you showed here is a *selection which walks the Abstract Syntax Tree upwards*. This different from the *evaluation order* of an expression. If an editor wants to have such functionality, it needs to parse the language (and not only to tokenize it).

IntelliJIDEA usually has this feature for many of the supported custom language plugins and of course for Java, Python, etc. which they support natively. The [Mathematica Plugin for IDEA](http://mathematicaplugin.halirutan.de/) parses the code and therefore, provides what you want

[image: Selection]

For JavaScript, HTML and C there exist support too, so you will most likely have this feature. Just install the community edition of IDEA and try it. For C you will need the C-plugin.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't need to parse the language. Emacs has this with the excellent [expand-region(https://github.com/magnars/expand-region.el) by [@magnars](https://github.com/magnars).

Comment: @cmpitg You are mistaken. If you really want to select expression-wise, you need to know the rules of the specific language. Take for instance these two examples: `a + ! b*c + c` and `a + b!*c + c` and start expanding the selection with the cursor before the `*`. You get two totally different selection ways depending on that + is the usual plus, * is the usual times, and ! is logical not and factorial resp. This interpretation is different for different languages. Your selection mode differs from what I mean and what I explained.

Comment: Do you know if such functionality exists in Visual Studio or xcode.  If not I'm really surprised.  (Also I proposed an edit to fix the url to http://www.mathematicaplugin.halirutan.de/ from the /start address).

Comment: @LiamWilliam Thanks, I fixed the link. For your questions, look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4979371/1078614) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2787239/1078614).